# While loop will not stop in recursive binary search

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, search, binary-search

I am trying to program a recursive binary search algorithm in python. However, I keep running into an infinite while-loop. I am afraid that it must be something simple that I am overlooking, but I cannot find the answer anywhere, most questions about while-loops not terminating do use other conditions and not boolean values.

The algorithm does seem to work, it prints the index of the element that I am searching for, or "Value not found" when the element is not in the list. But the while loop does never terminates, Even though i set found = False after the value has been found/not found. Why is this?

```
def binarysearch(A, v, x, y):
found = True
while found:
    if x < y:
        h = (x+y) //2
        if A[h] < v:
            binarysearch(A, v, h+1, y)
        else:
            binarysearch(A, v, x, h)
    elif A[x] == v:
        found = False
        print("Element you are looking for is at index {}".format(x))
    else:
        found = False
        print("Value is not in array")

#Code to test the binarysearch algorithm
blist = []
for value in range(0,124):
    if value % 2 ==0:
        blist.append(value)

print(blist)
binarysearch(blist, 68, 0, len(blist)-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `found` variable you are modifying with `found = False` is *local* to the scope of that particular recursive call to `binarysearch`. It is not the instance of `found` you are *trying* to modify, i.e. the one in the top level of the recursion tree. So although the `while`-loop in the current scope will terminate, the loops in the scopes above it will not.

Since you already have a mostly complete loop implementation, instead of using recursion on top of it (which is causing the scope-related error) you can just narrow the search range by overwriting `x` and `y`.

```
def binarysearch(A, v, x, y):
    found = True
    while found:
        if x < y:
            h = (x+y) //2
            if A[h] < v:
                x = h+1  // replaced
            else:
                y = h    // replaced
        elif A[x] == v:
            found = False
            print("Element you are looking for is at index {}".format(x))
        else:
            found = False
            print("Value is not in array")
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I made was that I used a while loop ON TOP OF the recursive calls, which basically are two ways of accomplishing the same. For the people interested in the algorithm that uses recursion instead of a while loop to keep it running, I provided a working version of it below.

```
def binarysearch(A, v, x, y):
    if x < y:
        h = (x+y) //2
        if A[h] < v:
            binarysearch(A, v, h+1, y)
        else:
            binarysearch(A, v, x, h)
    elif A[x] == v:
        print("Element you are looking for is at index {}".format(x))
    else:
        print("Value is not in array")
```